# Getting guideline percentage value to a double variable in Android

Tags: android, drawable

I have divided my screen into 6 sectors using 4 Guidelines. I'v set the values into percentages. So by identifying percentages I can detect the sector of the screen. In the code I imported Guideline using

```
Guideline glV1 = (Guideline)findViewById(R.id.glV1); //Verticle guideline 1
```

The percentage which I'm talking about is shown here

[image]

Now I want to get that percentage (36%) value of that Guideline to a double variable. I googled but I didn't find any answer. Anyone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LayoutParams` for `ConstraintLayout`. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html). Below is some code that will return the value you seek. The guideline's id is set as "guideline" in the XML for `activity_main`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Guideline guideline = (Guideline) findViewById(R.id.guideline);

    double percent = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideline.getLayoutParams()).guidePercent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You just saved my day!